# AttributeError on import csv

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm just at a total loss and can't find anything I understand as being relevant either here at SO or with google.

```
>>> import csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "csv.py", line 6, in <module>
r = csv.read(f)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python script is named `csv.py`. You need to rename it to something else. Never name your script with the same name as a module.

1. Change the name of your script
2. Delete the csv.pyc also from the location where you created your csv.py file.

Should work after this.

Further, as pointed out in comments, `csv` module does not have a `read()` method.

Small example from official documentation

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Comment: @hcwhsa: Thanks. Didn't notice the method call by OP.

Comment: The issue was indeed a script ~/csv.py. I have no idea what the file was, the contents were foreign to me. Something from an old tutorial is all I can think.
The error made me think there was actually something wrong with the csv module, but now I'm thinking I need to take a moment and review exactly what it is that import declarations do.